# What does @aar signify in a gradle dependency declaration?

Tags: gradle

What is the significance of `@aar`; What is the difference between:

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
```

and

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3@aar'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below two are equivalent, the first line is short hand for the second line:

```
runtime "org.groovy:groovy:2.2.0@jar"
runtime group: 'org.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '2.2.0', ext: 'jar'
```

As you can see the `@xxx` is the extension of the dependency file/archive. If you do not specify `@aar` the default is `@jar`

Comment: it can be used this command to show the difference:

`gradle -q dependencies`

it can show whether the inner dependence is added to the project